# Cannot insert the value NULL into column ... Exception issues

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I'm having issues with a database uploadscript. It basically just adds all entities from a backup source to the database.

However, as some fields of the new database are non-existent in the old data source, I assign them default values. See screenshot below for examples, the string property `CCP1_description` (and the similarly named descriptions below that) are being set to `"Enter description here."`

However, when I save the entity, I get an Exception saying that the description field is not allowed to be NULL. Which it clearly isn't.

See screenshot for code + Exception

[image: screenshot of issue]

Here's a snippet from my database creation script, it shows how the columns have been set up:

```
...
[CCP1_description] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
[CCP2_description] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
[EP1_description] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
[EP2_description] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
[EP3_description] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
[EP4_description] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
[EP5_description] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
...
```

If I check my `temp` variable when debugging, I can clearly see the content of the description fields (all are `""Enter description here.` like they should be.

[image: screenshot2]

I know that a lot of things can cause this exception; but I don't see the root cause of this issue. Can someone shed some light on this? I have no idea why this exception is thrown...

I found many open questions with the same error, but I think this is a different situation because my fields are not databasegenerated, nor are they PK or IDENTITY fields. They are not empty when the entity is being constructed, and the object that is being added actually has the correct values.

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that the first 83 entities are added correctly. The exception is thrown on the 84th time the code is executed (and a lot of times after that.
Which means the issue is probably within another property field.

I checked all the fields, the only `null` values I encounter are added in fields that have been set nullable in the database and entity framework.

And now I really don't get why an exception is thrown on the description fields.

**UPDATE 2**

It seems this application was coded by Salvador Dali.

I reworked the code, but this time, I commented out the `.AddObject(temp);` line. Which means the entities are created, but never added to the db context. The `db.SaveChanges();` call should then actually be redundant and do nothing at all.

Or so I though. Turns out, my entities are still being added. I stepped through the entire code execution, it never uses the db context in any way except for the `db.SaveChanges();`, yet it still all gets added.
Conversely, if I only start adding the entities after a counter has reached 100 (which means only item 100, 101, 102, ... will be saved, all the rest will not be added), it stil keeps adding the other entities as well.

I have no clue at all. Literally none. I'll update the post once I know more.

**FINAL UPDATE**

I managed to find a workaround (see my answer below). However, I'm still looking for an explanation why this is happening. If anyone can explain this to me, I'll award them the answer to this question.

Comment: You are not showing all code. Is that tmp variable the only object being inserted in the DB?

Comment: Yes. There is a bigger foreach loop, but the `db.SaveChanges();` has been moved inside the foreach block for debugging purposes. So when it is called only 1 entity is being created.

Comment: try reducing to the simplest possible scenario first: instantiate db, add 1 object, save: does it still fail?

Comment: Can you trace the SQL being run at the time and see what's actually getting passed to the DB?

Comment: For some reason my SQL Profiler stopped working; I don't know of another way to trace the SQL commands. I did check every entity in my Debug Watch. The last correctly saved entity differs from the first erroneous entity only by one FK field (it is still a valid ID), and a few dates/strings that have changed. No structural differences, no new null-fields that weren't null before, etc... I don't have any idea about what the issue is because the Exception thrown is absolutely incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get a bit further in the code. I've changed the order of operations. It used to be:

```
//1. initialize temp
//2. fill in temp; field by field.
//3. if any missing (required) fields are encountered during step 2, then continue the foreach loop and take the next element (no save)
//4. else, add to database ad save changes
```

Somehow, And I cannot explain this, the entitiy gets saved automatically. If I run the exact same code as above but without the `.AddObject()` function, it still gets added.

So I changed my code to:

```
//1. Find all fields that will be needed for the entity
//2. If any required field is stille empty, continue the foreach loop
//3. initialize temp (inline initialization with all properties)
//4. Add object and save.
```

This doesn't really solve the original problem, it's just a workaround. If anyone can provide me with an explanation why these entities are being added, I will accvept that as the solution to my problem.